# How to convert MySQL query results into JSON object

Tags: mysql

I intend to format MySQL query results into the format suitable for a dashboard widget. The required format of the data looks like this:

```
[{"label": "Name", "value":"Age"}, {"Amy":"4", "Sheryl":"5"}]
```

However, currently, MySQL output looks like the following:

```
[{"Name": "Amy","Age":"4"}, {"Name":"Sheryl","Age":"5"}]
```

I am looking for a MySQL query that could format the output below into the format above. This basically requires us to

1. extract out the 2 headers, namely Name and Age,
2. convert the names and ages into key value pairs as the second element in the output array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this.

example:

```
| name | age|
| Mike | 23 |
| Roger| 25 |
```

Output would be:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "age": 23
  },
  {
     "name": "Roger",
     "phone": 25
  }
]


SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('name', name, 'age', age)) from yourTable;
```

another answer

```
SELECT json_object('name', name, 'age', age) FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Hi, I can't use the json_object function as when I tried with your second solution, the data response result in the widget shows something like this: `[{"json_object('Name', Name, 'Age', Age)": "{\"Age\": 4062238, \"Name\": \"Amy\"}"}]`

Comment: Can you share your sql table structure and columns names and what is the output you get?

Comment: The table structure is very simple, just with 2 columns promotion name and the revenue generated. The code just looks like this, `SELECT json_object('name', PromotionName, 'rev', Revenue) FROM data;` and the output looks like this `{
    "json_object('name', PromotionName, 'rev', NetRevenue)": "{\"rev\": 70, \"name\": \" Jan-May Promotion 2019 (Online)\"}"
  }`

Comment: Data looks good to me. Can you try this once SELECT CONCAT(
    '[', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('name', name, 'age', age)),
    ']'
) 
FROM yourTable;